# rectangle collision detection xna

Tags: c#, xna, collision

Hi everyone I've recently started to make my own platform game, I've managed to create the map using a 2d array and have also created my player with movement.
I'm now stuck on how to approach the rectangle collision side any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is how I have created my map and now I just need to figure out how to approach the collision.

```
    List<Texture2D> tileTextures = new List<Texture2D>();
    private const int tileWidth = 64;
    private const int tileHeight = 64;


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Camera camera)
    {         
        int tileMapWidth = tileMap.GetLength(1);
        int tileMapHeight = tileMap.GetLength(0);

        for (int x = 0; x < tileMapWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < tileMapHeight; y++)
            {
                int textureIndex = tileMap[y, x];
                Texture2D texture = tileTextures[textureIndex];

                spriteBatch.Draw(
                    texture,
                    new Rectangle(x * tileWidth - (int)camera.cameraPosition.X,
                        y * tileHeight - (int)camera.cameraPosition.Y,
                        tileWidth,
                        tileHeight),
                    Color.White);
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: From what I remember When I was starting with XNA, you had this rectangle class with an intersects method that you could use to determine whether an object was colliding with another

Comment: Do you know how I would compare my player rectangle with my tiles though? As i set a new rectangle each time in the tile draw function but I have no idea how I would actually call it to be checked if it was intersecting.

Comment: if you're doing XNA, you should probably have an `update`, method, and you can just iterate over all your players, and tiles, and make a new rectangle, and check for collisions there

Comment: So I've created a function for my player as follows:

public Rectangle BoundingBox
        {
            get {
                return new Rectangle(
                 (int)position.X,
                 (int)position.Y,
                 spriteWidth,
                 spriteHeight);
                }
          }

but I'm still unsure how to retrieve the tile rectangle from the code I posted above so I can use the intersects function, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: [Honestly it's not that hard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx) of your object and use it's [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersects.aspx) method to check wheter they have collided or not.

You can find a really simple example of how to check rectangle collisions on my [blog](http://nahuelianni.azurewebsites.net/06-killing-enemies/), where the user clicks over an enemy to destroy it:

```
if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
   for (int index = this.enemies.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
   {
       if (this.enemies[index].Intersects(
              new Rectangle((int)this.mouseCoordinates.X, 
                            (int)this.mouseCoordinates.Y,     
                            this.mouseTexture.Width, 
                            this.mouseTexture.Height)))
       {
            this.enemies.RemoveAt(index);
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Nahuel Ianni said is great for detecting collision. Now, you didn't specify what you need collision for, and I can see that you will most likely need it for *destroying enemies and bullets*, which @Nahuel Ianni explained wery well, but I think you'll also need *collision between player(s) and walls*.

Shaun Spalding made a great point in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IysShLIaosk) (for GameMaker) on how to detect and resolve collision in a platformer, which can also used in birds-eye-view game. In short, in his tutorial he explains you how you should get the `nextRectangle`* of your player and check if its colliding any walls, and if it is, just move the player right next to that wall. This way you won't see player(s) inside a wall for a frame / player(s) won't be stuck in walls.

*`nextRectangle` stands for the `Rectangle` (body) of your player, moved by the speed/force (whatever logic works for you). That's the *body in the next frame*. So you can say that you'll need to look into the future of your gameflow to get the best result for collision (and avoid players inside walls).

Answer (score 0):

Each Object that you want to check for collisions should have a `Rectangle` in it. That way, you can do

```
bool isHit=obj1.Rect.Intersects(obj2.Rect);
```